# How use dlib in Xcode C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, build, compiler-errors, dlib

I have installed dlib using Homebrew.

```
brew install dlib
```

Did this:

- Add `/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.16/include` to **Header Search Paths**
- Add `/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.16/lib` to **Library Search Paths**
- Add `-ldlib` to **Other Linker Flags**
- Add `Accelerate.framework` and change status to "Required" in **Link Binary With Libraries**

But when I include dlib's .h files have error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_", referenced from:
          _dlib_check_consistent_assert_usage in main.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

P.S. Yes, i used -v, but it's no effects

Comment: Not enough information. What is the actual error report, not just the last line of it.

Comment: @MarekR update.

Comment: Have you checked if your dlib dependencies are installed? You need MKL I think.

Comment: @newkid Yes, I checked, it's ok. I download and install MKL, same error. I should add MKL to the project?

Comment: Yeah you must link all dependencies for DLIB

Comment: @newkid how can i do it?

Comment: If you visit the [brew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dlib) for `dlib` you can see that it depends on `blas`,  `jpeg` and `libpng`. Now these dependencies are installed along with `brew install` thus, you can find the header paths and libraries to link.

Comment: AFAIK `dlib` should be preinstalled with Xcode so `brew install dlib` is not needed. Error message may indicate that library is build for different target than your application.

Comment: @newkid I add `*/include` and `*/lib` for `blas`, `jpeg` and `libpng` in **Header Search Paths** and **Library Search Paths** (if i right understand you), but have same error.

Comment: @MarekR I'm trying to run [this example](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/dnn_face_recognition_ex.cpp)